# Overload built-in (intrinsic?) function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang, built-in

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

double log(double) { return 42; }

int main() {
    std::cout << log(1) << std::endl;
}
```

While build debug version all used compilers (msvc,gcc,clang) prints `42`.

But when i try build (and run) in release mode i got:

- compilation error in msvc: `error C2169: 'log' : intrinsic function, cannot be defined`;
- prints `42` for gcc;
- prints `0` for clang.

Why release/debug results are different for same compiler?

Why got different results for different compilers in release mode?

Comment: You cannot redefine any standard function except a handful of explicitly allowed ones. This is undefined behaviour. Undefined means anything at all can happen, including your computer 'sploding on you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining a function that is already declared in `<math.h>` with external linkage.

C11 standard, §7.12.6.7:

> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double log(double x);
> ```

§7.1.2:

> Any declaration of a library function shall have external linkage.

[extern.names]/3:

> Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage
>   is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with extern "C"
>   linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.

According to [reserved.names]/2 the behavior is undefined; The implementation can thus do what it wants, including the issuance of nonsensical error messages.

Answer (score 2):

So according to the standard (17.6.1.2.4):

> In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).

It's unspecified whether or not the `log()` in `math.h` (really `cmath`) is in namespace `std` or not. If it is (like it is for libstdc++ for gcc), then calling `log(1)` quite simply calls your function because the other one is named `std::log()`. But for clang, apparently it puts it in the global namespace. Since there is a

`template <typename T> double log(T x);`

That will be preferred to yours since you're passing an int, so on clang it will call that one. (I can't check this right now since I can't access coliru and don't have clang installed, but this is a best guess).

Comment: Excellent !  But that doesn't fully explain the difference of result between release and debug version, where we expect some consistency of the compiler's behaviour.

Comment: It is specified that `log` in `math.h` is in the global namespace, and also may be in the std namespace; and `log` in `cmath` is in the std namespace, and also may be in the global namespace.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't explain it. It's actually kind of confusing. I have pretty little confidence in my answer to be honest.

Comment: "we expect some consistency". No we actually don't. Undefined behaviour means anything can happen. "Anything" includes different results in debug and release builds, and it's quite reasonable to expect those, as opposed to e.g. a nuclear missile launch. The latter is formally an OK event in the case of undefined behaviour, but not too likely to actually happen unless your computer directly controls ballistic missiles.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I think you and Columbo have the better answer here, so I upvoted him.